# Grant access if URI contains MAC / salted hash / specific pattern

Tags: apache

want to grant access to my apache server directory only if the URI follows a specific pattern.

The URI should look like `/pathname/hash/` with hash being a salted md5() hash over pathname and a fixed salt - e.g. md5("pathname"+"salt").

A valid URI would be `/pathname/4f665f05ecc4d56aa0f91de363967043/`

Apache supports md5() within [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#functions), but I don't know how to compare a part of the URI (determined by regex) with the md5() function whose argument also is another part of the URI (also determined by regex).
Is this possible? I don't know how to start...

Comment: There are too many answers to "I don't know where to start" questions to fit well with how this site works.   In addition, programming questions are usually asked at StackOverflow.com, although they like to see what you have tried so far and a description of unexpected behavior.

Comment: Is `/pathname` a physical filesystem path (file and/or directory?) that you are wanting to grant access to? Or is `/pathname` just a URL path that you later route through your application should the above check be successful?

Comment: This is certainly possible. I don't know if this question is salvageable on Webmasters, but if you'd like to post this on StackOverflow, addressing the points raised above, (and _@pingme_) I can throw down an answer. How this URI relates to your application (as per my comment above) could determine one of two ways to approach this problem.